# Android things with 4 pin Bi polar step up motor

Tags: android, android-things

Using android things (Pico i.MX7D I/O) **how to control 4 pin Bi polar step motor**. Can u solve me the pin configuration. [This is my set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mca4.jpg)

if any one know about step up motor please help me...[image][image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://duvindu92.blogspot.ru/2013/07/driving-bipolar-stepper-motor-with.html) description and [this](https://github.com/abhi007tyagi/Android-Things/tree/master/Motor_Control_L293D) and [that](https://github.com/zugaldia/adafruit-motor-hat) repo. There are many examples for google request "cd rom stepper motor" especially with "arduino" keyvord. Take a loot at that examples and convert it to Android Things GPIO.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Sir,Should I set "Pwm" enable.

Comment: No. PWM controls pulse width, but you need switching sequence like described [here](http://engineeronadisk.com/book_modeling/cont_acta3.html#868891)

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko I am usind ** L293 D** driver for this step motor.https://cdn.instructables.com/F4K/W7QL/JACTW5DX/F4KW7QLJACTW5DX.LARGE.jpg ,And there is PWM pins ... I had done as their description.

Comment: That is PWM pins for 2 DC motor PWM control (and "PWM" here is only name, there is no PWM driver in  L293). For bipolar stepping motor you need schematics like Figure 6 [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf). And there is no PWM - only pulse sequences on `Control A` and `Control B` inputs.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Sir, Now it working properly ,There was some hardware problems not in the codes. Thanks for your commitment.Thank you sir

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Please consider posting the solution to this question as an answer, so it can be accepted and is more visible for others coming to this question later.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko actually better stepper motors are almost always PWM current controlled, but typically by a current sensor in the driver amplifier circuit, not but the main processor.  That does not however appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is must be the code...
If any buddy need try this

```
public class mySampleStepper extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button_forward,button_backward;
private static final String[] leftMotorPins = { "GPIO_10", "GPIO_35", "GPIO_33", "GPIO_128" };
private ULN2003 mLeftStepper;
private int minSpeed=100;
StepDuration stepDuration;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_sample_stepper);
    button_backward=findViewById(R.id.button_forward_ID);
    button_forward=findViewById(R.id.button_backward_ID);

     stepDuration = new StepDuration(0, minSpeed);

    try {
        mLeftStepper = new ULN2003(leftMotorPins[0], leftMotorPins[1], leftMotorPins[2], leftMotorPins[3]);
        mLeftStepper.open();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "Error opening steppers", e);
    }

    button_forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLeftStepper.setDirection(Direction.CLOCKWISE);
            mLeftStepper.performStep(stepDuration);
        }
    });
    button_backward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLeftStepper.setDirection(Direction.COUNTERCLOCKWISE);
            mLeftStepper.performStep(stepDuration);
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        mLeftStepper.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "Error opening steppers", e);
    }
}
```

}

### **PIN Configuration**

I am using stepper driver(*L293D driver*)  between android things and stepper motor.[image: L293D driver]

pin connection

- **GPIO_10** connected to **c1b** (on L293D drive)
- **GPIO_35** connected to **c2a**
- **GPIO_33** connected to **c1a**
- **GPIO_128** connected to **c2b**
- Output 1,Output 2,Output 3 and Output 4 to the stepper motor respectively

*happy coding :)*